# Can we run DPDK application on OpenWrt linux os?

Tags: linux, intel, router, openwrt, dpdk

We have developed a DPDK application which is working fine on Centos OS.

We now have a requirement to run this on a router which has a simple [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/).

From the DPDK developers guide, they mention that it can be run on any LINUX but they have tested and compiled on

- FreeBSD 10
- Fedora release 20
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Wind River Linux 6
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5
- SUSE Enterprise Linux 11 SP3

Will the DPDK application be supported on OpenWrt machine as well ?. Your information will be of great help to me.

Thanks
Abhinay

Answer (score 1):

there are some others trying this - see https://lists.openwrt.org/pipermail/openwrt-devel/2015-January/030341.html

Answer (score 0):

DPDK mostly depends on a few things:

- Hugepage (Linux Kernel support) to get around TLB bottleneck
- UIO (Linux Kernel support) for user space poll mode driver to get good I/O performance
- Fine core affinity control (pthread and Linux Kernel sysfs /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX, isolcpus)

Since I don't have any OpenWRT system around, I would suggest that you try compile it on OpenWRT first, making sure it has all the things needed by DPDK, e.g. UIO support, supported NIC, etc. Once you make sure it compiles, first test with testpmd to see if it works. If it runs, great. Then you can verify testpmd with "set fwd=txonly" and connect the port to another machine to see it you can receive any traffic.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of request DPDK now officially supports openwrt https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/howto/openwrt.html